# What does the neutral colony do?

Tags: offworld-trading-company

At the beginning of the game, there is a neutral colony named "New Berlin".

**Later in the game, what the players and AIs can do with this colony ?**

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Neutral Colony has the following effects:

**-The colony adds artificial market pressures to the game mostly in power, food, water, oxygen and fuel.**

**-The larger the colony the more a pleasure dome will produce.**

**-If the colony dies from overpriced something all players lose the game**

There is an ongoing discussion going on [here on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Offworld/comments/32qg4c/the_neutral_colony_mechanics/) about the characteristics and effects of a Neutral Economy.